# how to check if tags exists - azure policy

Tags: json, azure, tags, azure-policy

I'm trying to check if the tags do not exist in a resource.
the tags are inserted from an array parameter named ExcludeTags, in the following format: Key;Value,Key;Value

this is the code:

```
{
    "count": {
        "value": "[parameters('ExcludeTags')]",
        "name": "tag",
        "where": {
            "field": "[format('tags[{0}]',split(current('tag'),';')[0])]",
            "equals": "[split(current('tag'),';')[1]]"
        }
    },
    "equals": 0
},
```

but when i upload the policy, i get the following error:

> The policy definition 'the policy id' rule is invalid. The 'field' property value '[format('tags[{0}]',split(current('tag'),';')[0])]' is invalid. 'field' and 'current' functions are not supported in the 'field' accessor.

does anyone know a better way to do that?

thank you

Answer (score -2):

- There are two commands for applying tags `New-AzTag` and `Update-azTag` through PowerShell. you can replace all tags on the resource group, subscription using `New-AzTag`

**You can apply set of tags to your storage account using given command:**

```
$tags = @{"Dept"="Finance"; "Status"="Normal"}
$resource = Get-AzResource -Name demoStorage -ResourceGroup demoGroup
New-AzTag -ResourceId $resource.id -Tag $tags
```

- If you run your command with different tags than erlier tag will remove.

```
$tags = @{"Team"="Compliance"; "Environment"="Production"}
New-AzTag -ResourceId $resource.id -Tag $tags
```

- For adding tags to those resources which have tags already.

```
$tags = @{"Dept"="Finance"; "Status"="Normal"}
Update-AzTag -ResourceId $resource.id -Tag $tags -Operation Merge
```

- The same commands also work with resource groups or subscriptions. You pass in the identifier for the resource group or subscription you want to tag.
- To add a new set of tags to a resource group, use:

```
    $tags = @{"Dept"="Finance"; "Status"="Normal"}
    $resourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name demoGroup
    New-AzTag -ResourceId $resourceGroup.ResourceId -tag $tags
```

For complete information you can check this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources?tabs=json).

Comment: thank you for commenting, but I want a policy, not a runbook.
so if you know how i can do that in a policy it will be great

Comment: Hey Daniel Saada, had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?